# How to keep state and prevent re-render of react component after changing hierarchy?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We have:

1)Two presentation components - `PresentationOne`, `PresentationTwo`. And it is impossible to achieve their effects using styles.

2)Component that uses state (class or useState) under the hood - `ComponentWithState`. It may be component from any library. Some kind of drop down list, for example. So, we can't use context or pass state from outside.

3)Button that changes presentation class - `ToggleButton`.

```js
export const PresentationOne = props => {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

export const PresentationTwo = props => {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

export const ComponentWithState = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(Math.random());
  return state;
};

export const ToggleButton = props => {
  return <div onClick={props.toggleEffect}></div>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [applyEffect, setApplyEffect] = useState(false);
  const toggleEffect = () => {
    setApplyEffect(!applyEffect);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {applyEffect ? (
        <PresentationOne>
          <ComponentWithState />
        </PresentationOne>
      ) : (
        <PresentationTwo>
          <ComponentWithState />
        </PresentationTwo>
      )}
      <ToggleButton toggleEffect={toggleEffect} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

ComponentWithState will be re-rendered with new state each time after click the button. Is it possible to get this architecture working? Is it possible to tell React that it is the same component like we can do with key prop inside lists?

Git repo with test suite: https://github.com/vitramir/test-react-hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the day of research it looks like the only way to achieve this (is usually named reparenting) is to use 3rd-party libraries like:

https://github.com/httptoolkit/react-reverse-portal

https://github.com/jaredly/react-teleporter

There is an issue in React repo: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3965

And there is no solution for React Native. So, if you are reading this question and you know the solution, please write it down in comments :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the child to be a shared reference to one component you could try creating that element before you return your markup:

```
const App = () => {
  const [applyEffect, setApplyEffect] = useState(false);
  const toggleEffect = () => {
    setApplyEffect(!applyEffect);
  };
  // This compiles to a React.createElement call
  const childComponent = <ComponentWithState />
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {applyEffect ? (
        <PresentationOne>
          // childComponent is now being passed by reference (I think)
          {childComponent}
        </PresentationOne>
      ) : (
        <PresentationTwo>
          // same as above
          {childComponent}
        </PresentationTwo>
      )}
      <ToggleButton toggleEffect={toggleEffect} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

though I'm not sure if this achieves what you need it to

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work https://codesandbox.io/s/test-react-hierarchy-h4vjh

Comment: And it should not, because it will return the same DOM as result.

Comment: what is your end goal here? better performance? shared state?

Comment: if you just need to keep state you could cache it in local storage (though this will get messy with nested objects), or use a store like redux or maybe the reducer hook (useReducer). Preventing renders is a bit different, and in general is probably an anti pattern unless you are solving a performance problem

Comment: I found react issue about exactly what I mean:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3965

Comment: ComponentWithState is blackbox with useState. We can't replace it with redux.